# Formal definition of a monotonically increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, definition, monotone-functions

My professor is working with the definition that a function is monotonically increasing when $x_1<x_2. \implies f(x_1)<f(x_2)$. Is this definition correct?

And most importantly, if we already know that a function is increasing, and we know that $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$, can we prove that $x_1<x_2$?

Intuitively, we should be able to show this, but I lack the mathematical maturity to do it. Can somebody please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the definition is correct, and you can also prove the inverse. Try to do it by contradiction.

Comment: why didn't he use an iff statement, though?

Comment: In general, one tries to put as little information into a definition as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most widely accepted definitions for an increasing function are the following:

1. A **(monotonically) increasing** function, which says that $x_1 \leq x_2 \implies f(x_1) \leq f(x_2)$.
2. A **strictly (monotonically) increasing** function, which says that $x_1 < x_2 \implies f(x_1) < f(x_2)$.

These two definitions are not the same, as any constant functions are increasing but not strictly increasing. Your definition would fit into the second one.

As for your second claim, indeed it holds. The contrapositive of $x_1 < x_2 \implies f(x_1) < f(x_2)$ asserts that $f(x_1) \geq f(x_2) \implies x_1 \geq x_2$. If $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$ is known, then we must have $x_1 \leq x_2$ by the contraposition, i.e. $x_1 = x_2$ or $x_1 < x_2$. But $x_1 = x_2$ can't be true, for otherwise we have that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, so we indeed have $x_1 < x_2$.

---

**EDIT**: OP asked a follow-up question in the comment on why in this case we are able to prove the bi-implication from just the implication alone here, but not in general. To illustrate this, we first note that more precisely the definition of a strictly increasing function should say:
$$
\forall x_1 \in \mathbb{R}, \; \forall x_2 \in \mathbb{R}, \; x_1 < x_2 \implies f(x_1) < f(x_2)
$$
The reason we can prove the reverse implication stems from the following two facts:

1. For any real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, either $x_1 < x_2$, $x_2 < x_1$ or $x_1 = x_2$. That is, $<$ is a connex relation.
2. There are two arbitrary variables involved in the definition above. Thus, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are just dummy variables that can be replaced by any other symbols.

With the contraposition, we see that we obtain:
$$
\forall x_1 \in \mathbb{R}, \; \forall x_2 \in \mathbb{R}, \; f(x_2) \leq f(x_1) \implies x_2 \leq x_1
$$

Replacing the dummy variables give:
$$
\forall x_1 \in \mathbb{R}, \; \forall x_2 \in \mathbb{R}, \; f(x_1) \leq f(x_2) \implies x_1 \leq x_2
$$

The two steps done above do not work for any general statements but are rather very special property of the relation $<$.

Comment: You beat me to it! You even mentioned contrapositive which is exactly what I was going to write rather than by contradiction . +1

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed to know.

Comment: Sorry, I read it again and was left wondering: what prevents one from using this reasoning to prove the bi-implication of ANY proposition which has only a one-way implication? How do I know I'm not writing something like "if it has ears then it is a horse"?

Comment: @DanielGusmão you can refer to my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the standard definition of (non-strict) monotonicity allows for equality, hence the definition becomes $$x_1\leq x_2 \implies f(x_1) \leq f(x_2).$$ Second of all, to answer your question, the reverse implication is actually true as well. This is immediate from the definitions: suppose the above statement holds for some $f$, and take two $x_1,x_2$ such that $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)$. Now suppose for contradiction that $x_2 < x_1$. But then it follows from our definition of monotonicity that $f(x_2)\leq f(x_1)$. It couldn't be the case that $x_1=x_2$, so we get a contradiction. Therefore $$f(x_1)\leq f(x_2) \implies x_1 \leq x_2.$$